# Regarding Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

****How to Access the Contact Related Account Record using Process Builder Cananyone Please M>ake Me As ScreenShot**
what i am Giving in Contact Phone Number that should be updated to Account Phone Number Field using Process Builder**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the Account record? You can access related record fields through the same field-selection tree as any field on the same record. Type `Account` and click the one with a chevron next to it, you will see the next drop-down appear where you can then access the related `Account` record's fields and even the other records related to the `Account`.

Answer (score 4):

You can follow IDs in a Contact based PB process. The field you want to use for the parent account is AccountID as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Hope this is helpful,

Comment: It is Not Working , Please Give Me answer

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? Please provide the steps to reproduce the problem as you see it and I will be able to explain in a clear way. Thanks! :)